# Foreach 'attributes' in 'obj' find only 'Silver' and 'White'

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting, filter

UPDATE:

```
let obj = [{
  id: 0,
  rank: 5,
  attributes: [
    { trait_type: 'Background', value: 'White' },
    { trait_type: 'Skin', value: 'Silver' },
    { trait_type: 'Special', value: 'Red' }
  ]
},{
  id: 1,
  rank: 3,
  attributes: [
    { trait_type: 'Background', value: 'Green' },
    { trait_type: 'Skin', value: 'Cracked' },
    { trait_type: 'Special', value: 'None' }
  ]
},
{
  id: 2,
  rank: 1,
  attributes: [
    { trait_type: 'Background', value: 'Red' },
    { trait_type: 'Skin', value: 'Cracked' },
    { trait_type: 'Special', value: 'None' }
  ]
}]
```

Get the obj array find the values eg 'Silver' and 'White' that are in the attributes then map out the id and rank of 'Silver' and 'White'

for example:
Find ['Silver', 'White']
Return:

```
{0, 5}
```

eg
id and rank of attributes value 'Silver' and 'White' is id = 0 and rank = 5

Comment: Please provide expected result

Comment: Why do you expect the answer to be `[2, 1]`? If you search for `Silver` and `White` in the original array (obj), the answer should be `[0, 5]` ( id: 0, rank: 5 ).

Comment: so im just filtering the id and rank by finding the attributes value for silver and white if that make sense?

Comment: So  id and rank for silver and white is `[0, 5]`. Not `[2, 1]`.

Comment: I updated the solution, please check it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to use not only `.filter` but also [`.every`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/every) and [`.some`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

```js
let obj = [{id: 0,rank: 5,attributes: [{ trait_type: 'Background', value: 'White' },{ trait_type: 'Skin', value: 'Silver' },{ trait_type: 'Special', value: 'Red' }]},{id: 1,rank: 3,attributes: [{ trait_type: 'Background', value: 'Green' },{ trait_type: 'Skin', value: 'Cracked' },{ trait_type: 'Special', value: 'None' }]},{id: 2,rank: 1,attributes: [{ trait_type: 'Background', value: 'Red' },{ trait_type: 'Skin', value: 'Cracked' },{ trait_type: 'Special', value: 'None' }]}]

const myFind = (data, conditions) => data.filter(({ attributes }) => 
  conditions.every((term) => 
    attributes.some(({ value }) => value === term)
  )
).map(({ id, rank }) => [id, rank]);
    
console.log(myFind(obj, ['Cracked', 'None']));
console.log(myFind(obj, ['White', 'Silver']));
```

```css
.as-console-wrapper { max-height: 100% !important; top: 0 }
```

Comment: can you also make it an obj like show let obj = {id:0, rank:5}

Comment: @54x1 Just replace map with `.map(({ id, rank }) => ({ id, rank }))` this will return an array of found objects

Answer (score 0):

Drill down to the attribute objects with two `forEach()` loops, then use `Array.includes()` to see which attribute objects ones have a value of 'Silver' or 'Gold', and push those into the results array:

```js
let obj = [{
  attributes: [
    { trait_type: 'Background', value: 'Pink' },
    { trait_type: 'Skin', value: 'Silver' },
    { trait_type: 'Clothing', value: 'Turtleneck' },
    { trait_type: 'Eyes', value: 'Squinted' },
    { trait_type: 'Hair', value: 'Mullet' },
    { trait_type: 'Mouth', value: 'Freezie' },
    { trait_type: 'Accessories', value: 'Piercings' },
    { trait_type: 'Earbuds', value: 'White' },
    { trait_type: 'Special', value: 'None' }
  ]
},{
  attributes: [
    { trait_type: 'Background', value: 'Green' },
    { trait_type: 'Skin', value: 'Cracked' },
    { trait_type: 'Clothing', value: 'Biker Jacket' },
    { trait_type: 'Eyes', value: 'Eyepatch' },
    { trait_type: 'Hair', value: 'Straight' },
    { trait_type: 'Mouth', value: 'Freezie' },
    { trait_type: 'Accessories', value: 'None' },
    { trait_type: 'Earbuds', value: 'White' },
    { trait_type: 'Special', value: 'None' }
  ]
}]

const result = []

obj.forEach(obj =>
{
  obj.attributes.forEach(obj =>
  {
    if(['Silver', 'White'].includes(obj.value))
    {
      result.push(obj)
    }
  })
})

console.log(result)
```

Comment: I don't think this is what OP wants, but I guess it's hard to tell since they didn't provide output.